# ADC Read-Out-Array-Values displaced for one Entry

Tags: c, timer, stm32, dma, adc

The question is about the microcontroller STM32L031G6UxS.
I use a Timer to trigger the ADC and then I use the DMA to transfer the data (whole sequence) into RAM.
With the ADC I scan Channel 1, 8 and 9. Actually the data in the Read-Out-Array should folow this direction, because SCANDIR=0 (Scan from CH0 to CHx):

ADCReadOut[0]=ValueCH1

ADCReadOut[1]=ValueCH8

ADCReadOut[2]=ValueCH9

The strange behaviour I have at the moment is the folowing:

ADCReadOut[0]=ValueCH9

ADCReadOut[1]=ValueCH1

ADCReadOut[2]=ValueCH8

As you can see the values are displaced for one entry.

The code below shows the appropriate implementation.

```
#define GPIO_ADC_VP_PORT                    (ps_GPIO_PORT_A)
#define GPIO_ADC_VP_BIT                     (u32_GPIO_PIN_1)
#define GPIO_ADC_PREAMP_POS_PORT            (ps_GPIO_PORT_B)
#define GPIO_ADC_PREAMP_POS_BIT             (u32_GPIO_PIN_0)
#define GPIO_ADC_PREAMP_NEG_PORT            (ps_GPIO_PORT_B)
#define GPIO_ADC_PREAMP_NEG_BIT             (u32_GPIO_PIN_1)

#define ADC1_TRIGGER                        ( ADC_CFGR1_EXTSEL_2 )   /* TIM22 (TRGO) connected to TRG4 of ADC1 */
#define ADC1_SMPT                           ( ADC_SMPR_SMP_1 | ADC_SMPR_SMP_0 )   /* Sampling time: 12.5 ADC clock cylce */
#define ADC1_CHANNELS                       ( ADC_CHANNEL_1 | ADC_CHANNEL_8 | ADC_CHANNEL_9 )   /* VP, Preamp pos, Preamp neg */

#define ADC1_DMA                            ( DMA1_Channel1 )
#define DMA_DATA_COUNT                      ( 3 )

...    

/*--- TIM22 / ADC1 / DMA1 ---*/
v_Timer22_Init( pb_UseEdsk_Flag );
v_Adc1_Init( &au16_ReadoutBufferAdc1[0] );
v_Adc1_Calibrate();

/*--- Enable second level hardware ---*/
/* Enable DMA1 */
ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;

/* Enable ADC1 */
ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;

/* Start ADC1 and corresponding timer */
ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;
v_StartTimer22();

...

static void v_Timer22_Init( bool_t* pb_UseEdsk_Flag )
{
    /* OC1REF signal is used as trigger output: TRGO triggers ADC1 */
    ADC1_TIMER->CR2 |= TIM_CR2_MMS_2;

    /* Prescaler */
    if( *pb_UseEdsk_Flag )
    {
         ADC1_TIMER->PSC = ADC1_TIMER_PRESCALER_EDSK;
    }
    else
    {
         ADC1_TIMER->PSC = ADC1_TIMER_PRESCALER_ANALOG;
    }
    /* Auto reload register */
    ADC1_TIMER->ARR = ADC1_TIMER_RELOAD_VALUE;
    /* Delay until ADC1 is triggerd: duty cycle off time */
    ADC1_TIMER->CCR1 = ACD1_TIMER_CYCLE_OFF_VALUE;

    /* Configure channel 1 as output */
    ADC1_TIMER->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_CC1S;
    /* Configure channel 1 to PWM Mode 2 (OC1M = 0b111),
       channel 1 is inactive as long as TIM22_CNT < TIM22_CCR1 */
    ADC1_TIMER->CCMR1 |= ( TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_2 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_0 );
}

static void v_StartTimer22( void )
{
    /* Reset timer count register */
    ADC1_TIMER->CNT = 0;
    /* Start timer */
    ADC1_TIMER->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

static void v_Adc1_Init( uint16_t* pu16_MemAdr )
{
    /*--- ADC1 part ----*/    
    /* Select PCLK divided by 1 as ADC clock */
    ADC1->CFGR2 |= ADC_CLOCKPRESCALER_PCLK_DIV1;

    /* Enable voltage regulator */
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;
    /* Every time a trigger is received, 1 sequence is sampled */
    ADC1->CFGR1 &= ~ADC_CFGR1_DISCEN;
    /* Insert a delay after each conversion until the DR register is read */
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_WAIT;
    /* Enable hardware trigger on rising edge */
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_EXTEN_0;
    /* Set ADC1_TIMER as trigger source */
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC1_TRIGGER;

    /* DMA circular mode selected */
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_DMACFG;
    /* Enable DMA */
    ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_DMAEN;

    /* Sampling time in ADC clock cycles */
    ADC1->SMPR |= ADC1_SMPT;

    /* ADC1 Channels */
    ADC1->CHSELR |= ADC1_CHANNELS;

    /*--- DMA part ---*/
    /* Peripheral address */
    ADC1_DMA->CPAR = ( uint32_t )&ADC1->DR;    
    /* Memory address */
    ADC1_DMA->CMAR = ( uint32_t )pu16_MemAdr;    
    /* Number of data to transfer */
    ADC1_DMA->CNDTR = DMA_DATA_COUNT;    
    /* Priority: Very high */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_PL;    

    /* Disable Memory-To-Memory mode */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_MEM2MEM;
    /* Memory size: 16-Bit */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0;
    /* Peripheral size: 16-Bit */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0;
    /* Enable memory increment mode */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_MINC;
    /* Disable peripheral increment mode */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_PINC;
    /* Enable circular mode */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR |= DMA_CCR_CIRC;
    /* Data direction: Read from peripheral and write to memory */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_DIR;
    /* Disable transfer complete interrupt */
    ADC1_DMA->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_TCIE;
}

static void v_Adc1_Calibrate( void )
{
    /* Make sure that ADC1 is stabilized before the calib process starts */
    v_SysClk_BusyWaitUs( 10 );

    /* Stops ADC1 */
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTP;

    /* Check if ADC1 is disabled */
    if( ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADEN )
    {
        /* Disable ADC1 */
        ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADDIS;
    }

    /* Wait until ADC1 is disabled */
    while( ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADEN ) {}

    /* Start calibration */
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL;

    /* Wait until ADC1 is calibrate */
    while( ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL ) {}
}
```

Does anybody have an Idea what's wrong?
I guess that the DMA Pointer which show on the RAM is already increased by one, when Timer, ADC and DMA starts to work. Is that generally thinkable?

Comment: Some code will definitely help.

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: Can anybody help me, please?
Maybe a hint, what the problem could be.

Comment: Thank you for your help community!
The problem is solved by writing the following line after the calibration part.
ADC1->CFGR1 |= ADC_CFGR1_DMAEN;
Means the DMA transfer for the ADC must not be enabled before the calibration.